# Move search box on the top by using CSS animation

Tags: html, css

I need to move my search box when user focus on it. I am using css animation and that is working but not working fine. I want to make like the current search box is moving up but right now it is seems like new search box is replacing the current search box.

```js
$('input').focus(function(){
$('.search').addClass('fixed');
})

$('input').blur(function(){
$('.search').removeClass('fixed');
})
```

```css
body{
  margin:0
}
.banner{
  height:200px;
  background:#ff0000
}
.search{}
.search-bar{ height:50px; background:#666; padding-top:10px}
.search-bar input{width:100%; height:35px}
.animated{background:#fff; opacity:0; position:fixed; bottom:0; height:0px; transition:height 0.5s; width:100%}
.fixed .animated{ height:100%; opacity:1}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="banner">
    
  </div>
  <div class="search">
    <div class="search-bar">
      <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="animated">
        <div class="search-bar">
      <input type="text">
    </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why two inputs? Use one and move it.

Comment: I am not getting the animation effect by using one input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample having the same animation using only 1 search box (input)

```js
$('input').focus(function(){
  $('.search').addClass('fixed');
})

$('input').blur(function(){
  $('.search').removeClass('fixed');
})
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0
}
.banner {
  height: 200px;
  background: #ff0000
}
.search-bar {
  height: 50px;
  background: #666;
  padding-top: 10px
}
.search-bar input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px
}
.search {
  transition: bottom 0.5s, top 0.5s;
  background: #ddd;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 50px;
  top: 200px;
  bottom: 40%;
}
.search.fixed {
  transition: bottom 0.5s, top 0.5s;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="banner">

  </div>
  <div class="search">
    <div class="search-bar">
      <input type="text">
    </div>      
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Now is it going on bottom first then it is moving back to top. It is should move to top from its current potition

Comment: @Carlos Updated with a gray background so you'll see what happens, so when you say "going to bottom first", does it still do that?

Comment: verified but it is seems like coming from bottom

Comment: @Carlos By giving the height duration i your transition a higher value, i.e. `transition: height 0.8s, top 0.5s;`, you can make it "look" better

Comment: @Carlos The main problem is that depending on where your search is positioned in relation to the viewport, it reaches bottom before top if it is below the middle. To overcome that you need to match that with a different duration calculated on the actual distance, and to make it look perfect, you'll have to set it with your script.

Comment: @Carlos I made an update not animate top/height, but top/bottom. Does that look better for you?